# How to Sort object list

Tags: linq

Whatever I do I cant seem to sort a list by invoice name.
I have a client class that contains a Icollection of Invoices

My Repoistory

```
public Client FindClientById(string id)
        {

            Client client = RepositorySet.Include("Account").Include("Invoice").FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id && !c.IsDeleted);

            return client;
        }
```

On My controller

```
Client clientToEdit = _clientService.FindClientAndInvoicesById(id);
List<Invoice> SortedList = clientToEdit.invoices.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What's the output you get?

Comment: Does a name contains a number at its start? if so it should sort as number and not as text.

Comment: can you share the rest of the code to the end of the controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SortedList.OrderBy(x => x.field)
```

or

```
List<Invoice> SortedList = clientToEdit.invoices.ToList().OrderBy(o => o.Name);
```